# Django queryset on related field

Tags: django, postgresql, relational-database, django-related-manager

Django is to making a query much more complicated than it needs to be.

A `Sentiment` may have a `User` and a `Card`, and I am getting the `Cards` which are not in the passed `User's` `Sentiments`

This is the query:

`Card.objects.all().exclude(sentiments__in=user.sentiments.all())`

this is what Django runs:

`SELECT * FROM "cards_card" 
WHERE NOT ("cards_card"."id" IN (
    SELECT V1."card_id" AS "card_id" 
    FROM "sentiments_sentiment" V1 
    WHERE V1."id" IN (
        SELECT U0."id" 
        FROM "sentiments_sentiment" U0 
        WHERE U0."user_id" = 1
        )
    )
)`

This is a version I came up with which didn't do an N-Times full table scan:

`Card.objects.raw('
SELECT DISTINCT "id" 
FROM "cards_card" 
WHERE NOT "id" IN (
    SELECT "card_id" 
    FROM "sentiments_sentiment" 
    WHERE "user_id" = ' + user_id + '
    )
)')`

I don't know why Django has to do it with the N-Times scan. I've been scouring the web for answers, but nothing so far. Any suggestions on how to keep the performance but not have to fall back to raw SQL?

Comment: I would probably write this as `Card.objects.all().exclude(sentiments__user__id=user.id)`. Does that help at all?

Comment: You are a genius and a scholar! If you answer the question I'll mark it as the answer :). Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of writing this query without the subqueries would be:

```
Card.objects.all().exclude(sentiments__user__id=user.id)
```